# "device disconnected or multiple access on port" error

Tags: apt, process, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I'm programming in Python 3 on a Raspberry PI 4 running current Debian.  My program uses serial port `/dev/ttyS0` to send binary requests to a MP3 player board.  The documentation about the MP3 player board says it will respond to queries about the playing status.  The program loops after an MP3 is started playing to know when it is finished playing.

The program works well after a reboot of the RPi but gets an "device disconnected or multiple access on port" error on the second and later attempts to run.  The error still occurs if the MP3 player is restarted but not the RPi.  Changing timeout doesn't seem to prevent it.

What program or utility can I run to see what is accessing the port or what to do to prevent disconnect?

I think the problem is an OS issue and not a program problem but that is why I'm asking here.

```python3
"""Sends a  message via serial & receives back information via serial."""
 
import serial
import time
 
PLAYING_DONE = bytearray([0, 0, 0])
 
def write_command(port, command):
    """Write command to serial port"""
    command = [170] + command  # Command packet starts with 0xAA
    command.append(sum(command) % 256)  # Append checksum
    print(command)
    port.write(bytearray(command))
 
def read_status(port):
    """Read status?  Returns 3L bytearray"""
    write_command(port, [1, 0])
    bytes = port.read(5)
    if bytes[0] != 0xAA:
        raise ValueError('Serial sentinel error')
    if bytes[4] != (sum(bytes[:-1]) % 256):
        raise ValueError('Serial read checksum error')
    return bytes[1:-1]
 
def play_track(port, track_info):
    """Start playing track.  Track is??"""
    write_command(port, [7] + track_info)
 
with serial.Serial(
        '/dev/ttyS0',  #'COM3:',
        baudrate=9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=2) as ser:
    # Start of serial context
    play_track(ser, [2, 0, 4])  # Track info?
    playing = None
    while playing != PLAYING_DONE:
        time.sleep(4) 
        playing = read_status(ser)
        print(f'Status = {playing}')
    # end of serial context
print("I am done")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a patch or fix, but I started increasing the timeout parameter in the serial open statement and now, it doesn't give the error

serial.serialutil.SerialException: read failed: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)

I went up to 20 before it stopped giving an error, started at 2.  I suppose, that the chip on the MP3 board doesn't support a very fast serial port.

This just stopped the above error.  I still have work to do to get the whole return code back.  At this point, all I get back are zeros, no leading or trailing information like the documentation suggests.